My Ubuntu version 22.04 fails to start up
[FAILED] Failed to start tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures  
[FAILED] failed to start the authorization manager  
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for modem manager  
[FAILED] Failed to start dispatcher daemon for system-networkd  


not sure why you tagged modem-manager but you have given no indication of what you have tried in the meantime to save suggestions which you might say you have already tried causing further frustration being repeated. This article might help.
